# When measuring vinegar for salsa do I measure all vegetables or just the tomatoes?

Tags: measurements, vinegar, salsa

I'm using bell peppers, jalapeno peppers, onions, and tomatoes for salsa. How much vinegar do I need to add per cup or is the amount of vinegar just based on cups of tomatoes?

Comment: Are you using a recipe or just eye-balling the ingredients ? I'd probably use the total weight.

Comment: Is this a recipe for canning, or is it just to taste?

Answer (score 2):

If the salsa is for eating fresh immediately, then add vinegar to taste for whatever acidity you prefer at the end.

If it's for canned salsa, added acid is typically measured on a total weight basis for all ingredients to ensure everything, not just the tomatoes, reach a safe pH. If you added only enough acid for the amount of tomato, say for a low-tomato ratio peach or mango salsa, the unaccounted water may dilute the acid too much.

You can looking vinegar acidified salsa recipes and scale the amounts to your batch size.